# am4themes_animated ESlint error for import

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am using am4themes_animated in my angular project and am moving to eslint instead of tslint.

`import am4themes_animated from '@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated';`

However, ESlint is giving the following error.

`Identifier 'am4themes_animated' is not in camel case  camelcase`

I have tried using alias like `import am4themes_animated as am4themesAnimated from '@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated';` but it won't allow this.

This might be a very novice question but please if someone could help, would really appreciate it. Thanks.
(My first question here, so learning as I go, sorry if any mistakes)

**Update:**

`import *  as am4themesAnimated` does not work as I need the constant to be passed as a parameter like this: `am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);`

Comment: You can try like `import *  as am4themesAnimated from '@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated';`

Comment: Hi, tried your way but doesn't work. ```am4themes_animated``` is to be passed as a parameter (of type ITheme) here: ```am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed just by referencing am4Charts [Themes](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/themes/#Loading_a_theme) documentation.
We can basically name our imported theme anything we want.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information with an example code that you have implemented.